# ReactJS Module not found: Can't resolve './static/js/myfile.js'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am trying to learn React and I use "create-react-app". I now have an issue that I find very strange and am not able to solve.

I have a map-structure like this:

```
   administratie
   └─ public
      └─ static
         └─ img
         └─ js
   └─ src
      └─ content
```

In my content I have a Content.js that looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./Mut.css";
import { format } from "./static/js/date.js"; // Error

class Mut extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datum: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let today = format(new Date());
    this.setState({
      datum: today
    });
  }

  handleChange(event) {}

  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <img src="./static/img/administratie-logo.png" alt="logo" />  // Is rendered as it should
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default Mut;
```

On line 4 I import a .js-file from the static folder. On line 26 I show an image from the static folder. Now the image is shown nicely but the import gives me the error:

```
./src/content/Mut.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './static/js/date.js' in 'C:\react-projects\administratie\src\content'
```

The date.js file looks like this:

```
export function format(d) {
  let day = d.getDate().toString();
  if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

  let month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  if (month.length === 1) month = "0" + month;

  const year = d.getFullYear().toString();

  return day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
}
```

Any insight is hugely appreciated!

Comment: import { format } from "../public/static/js/date.js"; // Error

Comment: If you are in src folder you need to use ".." to go level up - when You are in administratie - you can go to public/static/js

Comment: import { format } from "../public/static/js/date.js"; is giving me the same error

Comment: ok - try add 'export default' - instead 'export'

Comment: And why does the "./" (single dot) work with the image?

Comment: import { format } from "../../public/static/js/date.js";

Comment: Now I get a different error: Module not found: You attempted to import ../../public/static/js/date.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: So double "../../" - go outside directory. with knowledge about "../" - is level up and './ is go level down you need to try variances and solve problem

Comment: Piotr Zak, your efforts are appreciated! Can you explain why "./static/js/date.js" does not work and why "./static/img/administratie-logo.png" does???

Comment: Yes, accordin to alrob - path is relative

Comment: Then both "./static/js/" and "./static/img" are relative. But one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL inside **`<img>`** tag is resolved at run time, by the browser. That is why, the image loads fine.

However, the Javascript file specified in the **import** statement will be resolved at the compilation time.

React looks for modules in the ***'src'*** and ***node_modules*** folders only.

The failing import statement is:

> import { format } from "./static/js/date.js"; // Error

React is throwing the error because **/static/js/date.js** does not exist in 
either **'src'** or **'node_modules'**

To make the code work, the ***date.js*** file can be copied to a location under the ***'src'*** folder.

(**node_modules** is for the dependencies downloaded through 'npm install')

Comment: It works. Thank you very much for your explanation Gopinath. You made my day!